# AutocompleteTextView printing object to string

Tags: android

I am using an ArrayAdapter with a custom object and the autocomplete text view is printing my custom object to string when i want it to display a field. I thought I could override my filter method like this

```
@Override
public CharSequence convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
    Tag result = (Tag) resultValue;
    return  result.getName();
}
```

This is called but seems to have no effect on the displayed result4

edit filter class

```
Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                resultList.clear();
                if (constraint != null) {
                    Iterable<String> iterable = st.keysWithPrefix(constraint.toString());
                    Iterator<String> iterator = iterable.iterator();
                    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                        String keys = iterator.next();
                        resultList.add(st.get(keys));
                    }
                    // Retrieve the autocomplete results.
                    filterResults.values = resultList;
                    filterResults.count = resultList.size();
                }
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
                Tag result = (Tag) resultValue;
                return result.getName();
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }
        };
```

Comment: Is getName() a custom function, or is it referring to the class name? What you have looks reasonable, so we'll need to see the code for the Tag class at least. Also, this override is in a custom filter class, right?

Comment: show more code from adapter

Comment: I added my filter class the getName() returns a string but the TextView is still showing Tag.toString() not Tag.getName()